# How do I read the "UserProperty" value in Outlook using MS Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, mapi

We have legacy code that writes custom data to the "UserProperties" collection of an Outlook AppointmentItem object.  We've now switched to using Outlook on the Web (OWA).

Using MS Graph, how does one retrieve these values?

I've been pouring over this documentation ([Outlook extended properties overview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/extended-properties-overview)) but I can't get it to work.  I'm using the [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Here is the event for which I'm trying to retrieve information custom data.

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('45d5e17d-348a-4ca8-b53c-c7d353b928b3')/events",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"GKUifH9QgE6zbEa7VG6rswABBwIJDw==\"",
        "id": "AAMkADU4MzkxN2RmLTdiZDAtNDIwYS04NjQzLTUzNzMyMjM0Y2VkNQBGAAAAAABGjw0ByCaySL6aUxJmew3qBwDwiT27qO5xT6RMWiWBhwRzAAAADIqqAADdUihFgnKFTYATejxXFszxADsYsAgxAAA=",
        "createdDateTime": "2018-07-11T19:17:12.340183Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-09-17T19:50:10.7118964Z",
```

I assume the "id" value of this event is the one that I should be using.

Here is the REST call I'm making (Note: using BETA)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events('AAMkADU4MzkxN2RmLTdiZDAtNDIwYS04NjQzLTUzNzMyMjM0Y2VkNQBGAAAAAABGjw0ByCaySL6aUxJmew3qBwDwiT27qO5xT6RMWiWBhwRzAAAADIqqAADdUihFgnKFTYATejxXFszxADsYsAgxAAA=')?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'Integer%20{0006303D-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20TaskID'  )
```

The UserProperty name is "TaskID" and it holds an Integer.   I'm not clear about what the GUID value should be.

I've tried the GUID of the AppointmentItem itself; then the GUID of the "UserProperties" collection contained within the AppointmentItem, and finally the GUID of the "UserProperty" property contained within the "UserProperties" collection.  Nothing has worked.

Any clues?

## CODE SAMPLE TO CREATE CUSTOM DATA

1. Create a VSTO project for Outlook
2. Copy paste code below
3. Create an appointment in your Outlook calendar
4. Update the subject line to "MS Graph - Extended Properties Test".
5. Close Outlook
6. Compile and run code.
7. Open your your appointment and make some (NOT to subject) and Save.
8. The add-in updates the body of your Appointment with the time of your save.
9. Try and retrieve this data using Microsoft Graph

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

   namespace AddCustomProperty
   {
       public partial class ThisAddIn
       {
           Outlook.Items _items;
           Outlook.Folder _calendar;
           Outlook.Inspectors _inspectors;
           const string sCustomData = "MyCustomData";

           private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
           {
               _calendar = this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Outlook.Folder;

              _items = _calendar.Items;

              _items.ItemChange += eventChange;

              _inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
              _inspectors.NewInspector += newInspectorWindow;


           }

           private void newInspectorWindow(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
           {
               Object oAppointmentItem = null;
               Outlook.UserProperties userProperties = null;
               Outlook.UserProperty userProperty = null;

               try
               {
                   oAppointmentItem = Inspector.CurrentItem;
                   if (oAppointmentItem is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                   {
                       userProperties = ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)oAppointmentItem).UserProperties;
                       userProperty = userProperties.Find(sCustomData);
                       if( userProperty != null)
                       {
                           ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)oAppointmentItem).Body = string.Format("MY CUSTOM DATA FOUND [{0}]: {1}\n", DateTime.Now, userProperty.Value);                    
                       }
                   }
               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
               }
               finally
               {
                   if (userProperty != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(userProperty); userProperty = null; }
                   if (userProperties != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(userProperties); userProperties = null; }
                   if (oAppointmentItem != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oAppointmentItem); oAppointmentItem = null; }
               }
           }

           private void eventChange(object Item)
           {
               Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem = null;
               Outlook.UserProperties userProperties = null;
               Outlook.UserProperty userProperty = null;

               try
               {
                   apptItem = Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

                   if (apptItem.Subject == "MS Graph - Extended Properties Test") 
                   {
                       userProperties = apptItem.UserProperties;
                       userProperty = userProperties.Find(sCustomData);
                       if( userProperty == null)
                       {
                           userProperty = userProperties.Add(sCustomData, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olInteger);
                           userProperty.Value = 10;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)apptItem).Body = string.Format("MY CUSTOM DATA FOUND [{0}]: {1}\n", DateTime.Now, userProperty.Value);

                       }

                   }
               }
               catch( Exception e)
               {
                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
               }
               finally
               {
                   if( userProperty != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(userProperty); userProperty = null; }
                   if (userProperties != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(userProperties); userProperties = null; }

               }            
           }

           private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
           {
               // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
               //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
           }

           #region VSTO generated code

           /// <summary>
           /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
           /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
           /// </summary>
           private void InternalStartup()
           {
               this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
               this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
           }

           #endregion
       }
   ```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your question? I have some doubts, such as `UserProperties`.

Comment: "UserProperties" is a collection of "UserProperty" objects.  It's contained within the AppointmentItem object.

UserProperties
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties

AppointmentItem
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem

Comment: NOTE:  I've attempted to add the $expand=extensions at the end of my call to MS Graph.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events?$filter=start/datetime eq '2018-08-25T22:30'&$expand=extensions

But that only returns an "InternalServerError" message

Comment: @Kikang Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I don't have a better solution yet, I will continue to follow up on this issue until I find the right solution.

Comment: @kikang
Thank you.  Let me know if you would like me to send you a sample project that would create the object under "UserProperties".   It would be a COM Add-In.

It would add a custom property to an Outlook Appointment ("Event").  You can then use the Graph API to inspect that Event.

Note:  OutlookSpy would be a good tool to inspect Objects created using COM.

Comment: It will  be very helpful to me.

Comment: @kikang:  I added a code sample with instructions.  It will add the custom data to the appointment (event).  Pardon the formatting.  The code begins with the first "Using" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received my answer in another site.

The problem lay with the GUID I was using in one of my queries.  I was using the GUID for the **UserProperty** object instead of the GUID for the Object that inherits from **UserProperty**

[INCORRECT GUID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6lJw.jpg)

The correct GUID came from the MAPI object itself.

[CORRECT GUID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJqC.jpg)

The final call looks as follows: [Complete Answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bde9ce93-5e8d-44c1-b6fc-96908d79dcf3/how-do-i-retrieve-extended-properties-from-a-calendar-event-using-ms-graph?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events('AAMkADU4MzkxN2RmLTdiZDAtNDIwYS04NjQzLTUzNzMyMjM0Y2VkNQBGAAAAAABGjw0ByCaySL6aUxJmew3qBwDwiT27qO5xT6RMWiWBhwRzAAAADIqqAAAYpSJ8f1CATrNsRrtUbquzAAEOAONsAAA=')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'Integer%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20MyCustomData')
```