# Need to create VSTO UserProperties with MS Graph

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-addins, microsoft-graph-api

We have an add in that works with user properties set as Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olInteger
I have been asked to integrate that with MSGraph.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376288/how-do-i-read-the-userproperty-value-in-outlook-using-ms-graph) post if user properties are created in a VSTO add in this can be accessed through MS Graph but how can I go the other way? I need to use [Outlook extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-beta) but I am not sure how

So far I am not sure how to add extended properties and how to pick them up in a VSTO add in

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the GUID for dealing with user properties. See [How do I retrieve Extended Properties from a Calendar Event using MS Graph?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bde9ce93-5e8d-44c1-b6fc-96908d79dcf3/how-do-i-retrieve-extended-properties-from-a-calendar-event-using-ms-graph?forum=WindowsAzureAD) for more information. For example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events('AAMkADU4MzkxN2RmLTdiZDAtNDIwYS04NjQzLTUzNzMyMjM0Y2VkNQBGAAAAAABGjw0ByCaySL6aUxJmew3qBwDwiT27qO5xT6RMWiWBhwRzAAAADIqqAAAYpSJ8f1CATrNsRrtUbquzAAEOAONsAAA=')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20MyCustomData')
```

[image: A user property set via MS Graph API]

Answer (score 0):

User properties are twofold: their definition is stored in a special blob (you can see its definition in [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button) and their value is stored as a regular named MAPI property (see the OutlookSpy screenshot in Eugene's answer). The blob format is documented, but parsing or (even worse) creating it is a major pain. If you don't need the property to be present in the `MailItem.UserProperties` collection, you can read or set its value using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`/`SetProperty` by the property DSL name (also shown by OutlookSpy). To read or set the value using Graph, you can use the link in your question.